# CSRF Token with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, csrf

I have a services layer project protected by spring security and a html5 project secured by saml.

When I'm trying to invoke rest APIs from my html5 app, GET requests are a success and I'm able to retrieve the data perfectly.

However, when I try to post/put data, then I'm getting the CSRF Token issue. I donot want to disable this in spring security as it could lead to potential malware attacks.

Can someone suggest me how to retrieve the csrf token from services layer and pass is back in the header while doing a post operation service call.

I searched online extensively but could not find the right link. Any pointers on this would be of immense help to me :)

Comment: can you show me a snippet of your post jsp form ? and what issue do you get on post ?

Comment: Did you try the documentation? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-csrf

Comment: Hi Mavenrick, currently in jsp I added following tags:                                 <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>                    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");        I see that the javascript variables are coming as NULL. I expect to get values in those variables so that I can pass it to Rest

Comment: Thanks Journeycorner for the doc link. But I'm not having any forms in my html5 app. I'm providing a CSV upload option which will post the data to user controller in html5 app. This user controller internally calls the service layer. So, my expectation is to pass csrf token from html5 app to user controller so that I can use this request/session attribute and pass the same to the actual restful webservice that is secured by spring

Comment: Just to re-clarify, only services project is spring security project. the html5 project is developed using JSP and saml authentication. In html5 project, when we make a post/upload action, an user controller is called which will internally invoke the rest api in services layer. So, I some how need to pass csrf token from html5 app or user controller to the actual rest api service call.

Comment: Can some one help me with this please :)